# Not able to receive chat messages using smackx MultiUserChat API

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, openfire, smack

I am trying to use smack API for Android to develop a chat room using gmail accounts. I managed to create a room and send messages to group. But when someone replies i am not able to receive incoming messages either directly on chat window or through program(muc.addMessageListener(myMessageListener) and PacketListener).

```
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    connection.connect();
    connection.login("kandroid6990@gmail.com", "password");
    muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, "private-chat-12325669-dead-beff-feed-fedcba987454@groupchat.google.com");
    muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
    muc.join("kandroid6990");
    muc.invite("karthikbaskar3@gmail.com/User1", "Welcome!");
    muc.invite("kamaraj6990@gmail.com/User2", "Welcome!");




    Message msg = new Message("private-chat-12325669-dead-beff-feed-fedcba987454@groupchat.google.com", Message.Type.groupchat);
    msg.addBody(Message.getDefaultLanguage(), messageText);
    muc.sendMessage(msg);
```

Comment: Are you get your answer

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
muc.addMessageListener(myMessageListener);
```

Comment: In my question through program refers to muc.addMessageListener(myMessageListener);
and PacketListeners

Answer (score 0):

```
private MultiUserChat   muc; /* Initialize muc */
private void listeningForMessages() 
 {
    muc.addMessageListener(new PacketListener() {
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) 
    {
        final Message message = (Message) packet;
        // Do your action with the message              
    }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help in receive group chat message 
Just implement group chat listener

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.groupchat);
XmppTool.con.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        Message message = (Message) packet;


            }
        }
    }
}, filter);
```

Comment: in smack 4.1.5 MessageTypeFilter is private access and so we couldn't implement this